# Export specific page/tab in Cognos Analytics 11 report to PDF

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos

I have a report with three different pages displayed as tabs whereas one of the pages is designed for PDF print. The issue I am facing is when I choose a specific tab to export to PDF, the two other pages/tabs are exported aswell. I only want the tab that is selected to be exported, not all of them.

The only option I see, is the "Run as PDF", there is no specific button that exports the current tab that is displayed when consuming the report.

I am using version 11.1.4 and this is when creating a report (not dashboard)

All tips, solutions and ideas are very appreciated.

Best regards,
Rubrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a string render variable on the page based on the ReportOutput() function.

Comment: So apply a render variable on all the pages/tabs ? ReportOutput() = 'PDF' with somekind of if satement ?. All the pages should be available for PDF print but the report has to be able to recognize which tab that you have currently selected, so that only that page is being exported. Then if I choose tab 2 it should export only that one to PDF.

Comment: The would be a string variable which merges ReportOutput() and PageName().  So you would have multiple conditions HTMLPage1 PDFPage1 HTMLPage2 PDFPage2.  With those you could set them on a per page basis.  The unfortunate part is PageName or Number does not appear to work with render variables so we need a different way to determine what page you are on.   I am still chewing on that part.